# Why is this happening with the matrix in C?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I have this function:

```
void changes_equation_order(double** system, unsigned int qty) {

    double aux[100];
     
     //first print
    for(int i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < qty; j++) {
            printf("%.1lf ", system[i][j]);
            if(i == 0)
                aux[j] = system[i][j];
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    remove_line(system, 0, qty);

    printf("\nReordering the matrix: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < qty; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < qty; j++) {

            if(i == qty- 1) {
                system[i][j] = aux[j];

            }

            printf("%.1lf ", system[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\Second print: \n");

    for(int i = 0; i < qty; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < qty; j++) {

            printf("%.1lf ", system[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

It receives a matrix with rows and columns with qty value, so, in the example, system is:

```
0   3   2
4   0   2
2   3   0
```

and qty equals to 3.

When I print the first time, the matrix is with the right value, so it gives me

```
0   3   2
4   0   2
2   3   0
```

When I print the second one (Reordering print), it reorders the matrix values and prints to me:

```
4.0 0.0 2.0
2.0 3.0 0.0
0.0 3.0 2.0
```

Which is correct, but when I print the matrix right after, it produces this:

```
4.0 0.0 2.0
0.0 3.0 2.0
0.0 3.0 2.0
```

Why is this happening?

Also, this is the remove_line function:

```
void remove_line(double** system, int row, unsigned int qty){
    qty--;

    free(system[row]);
    while(row < qty) {
        system[row] = system[row + 1];
        row++;
    }

}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: First of all please try to create a [mre] to show us. How do you call this `changes_equation_order` function? With what arguments? How are those arguments initialized?

Comment: Oh and remember that arguments passed to functions have their values *copied*. When you call the `void remove_linha` function, the value of the `qty` variable in `changes_equation_order` will be copied. The variable `qty` in the `remove_linha` function is totally separate even if it has the same name. Modifications to the `remove_linha` variable `qty` will only happen to that local variable. That means, after you call `remove_linha` the value of `qty` in the `changes_equation_order` function will be wrong.

Comment: Right! But if I'm printing the matrix inside the function, then it should persist at least, the right value, no?

Comment: No. Your printing function assumes that the call `remove_line(system, 0, qty)` changes the value of `qty` upon return, but it does not.

Comment: But this is right, I'm not trying to change the qty value. It should be this until the program finishes.

Comment: Sorry, it should be 4.0 0.0 2.0. Updated.

Comment: You call `changes_equation_order` with `qty` equal to `3`. The call to `remove_linha` happens. And after that `qty` is *still* equal to `3`. Is that what's expected after you "remove" a line from the matrix? What is `remove_line` really supposed to do?

Comment: Regarding the comment by @GraemeJensz, you may want to read this official help page: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) I especially recommend that you read this part: `"If your question has good answers, though, it's not fair to have those answers removed along with your question: other users put effort into helping you and even if you no longer want the answers, somebody else might."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen because `system[1]` and `system[2]` are pointing to the same memory after execution of `remove_line`. In other words, when you change, e.g. `system[2][0]` it will also change `system[1][0]`. They are the same memory.

To explain it with an example assume that the pointers `system[n]` has these values when you call `changes_equation_order`

```
system[0] = 0x1000;
system[1] = 0x2000;
system[2] = 0x3000;
```

then after executing `remove_line(system, 0, qty);` the values will be

```
system[0] = 0x2000;
system[1] = 0x3000;
system[2] = 0x3000;
```

As you can see `system[1]` and `system[2]` are now pointing to the same memory.

The first print seemed fine because you print the `system[1]` row before executing

```
        if(i == qty- 1) {
            system[i][j] = aux[j];

        }
```

where you are changing the `system[2]` row (but also the `system[1]` row as they are the same).

I'm not sure what you are trying to do in the remove_line function so I can't advice you. However, one advice....

Use separate loops for printing and modifying the matrix! I know that will give you some extra loops but your code will be much easier to understand.

For instance instead of:

```
printf("\nReordering the matrix: \n");
for(int i = 0; i < qty; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < qty; j++) {

        if(i == qty- 1) {
            system[i][j] = aux[j];

        }

        printf("%.1lf ", system[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

use multiple loops - like

```
printf("\nPrint before reestablish of last row: \n");
for(int i = 0; i < qty; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < qty; j++) {
        printf("%.1lf ", system[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Reestablish last row
for(int i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < qty; j++) {
        if(i == qty- 1) {
            system[i][j] = aux[j];
        }
    }
}

printf("\nPrint after reestablish of last row: \n");
for(int i = 0; i < qty; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < qty; j++) {
        printf("%.1lf ", system[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @GraemeJensz Why are you asking me?

Comment: @GraemeJensz Asking for homework help is ok on SO

Comment: Thanks, @4386427! I'll try to fix this by following what you said! Thanks so much!

Comment: Be careful, this question may be deleted and the tick removed by the question author.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking of passing all the values to another matrix, passing it to the remove_line function. Then, I can take its values and pass it to the system. What do you think?

Comment: The remove_line function removes a given row, in this case 0. I keep track of the removed line on the aux array. And then, after I removed the line, I append the deleted line on the matrix

Comment: @Another No you don't "append the deleted line on the matrix". You have already `free` it in `remove_line`. It's lost, gone, not existing anymore.

Comment: Right. But I get the deleted row on the aux array.

Comment: @Another No, not **the deleted row**. What you have in `aux` is **a copy** of the values. That's another thing. When you do `free(system[row]);` that row is just gone...

Comment: Thanks, @4386427! I've passed another matrix to the delete_line function, then, when the row is removed, I've passed the values to the system matrix and updated the last row. Thanks!